# Replace String in file using marker in Java

Tags: java, string, replace

i have problem when try to replacing String in File.
in my file i have :

```
<!-- Header -->
<header fontName="Arial" size="24"/>
<!-- Content -->
<content>
    <fontName="Arial" size="11"/>
</content>
```

How to replace fontName and size just for `<!-- Header -->` ?

This is my code for replace

```
public class StringReplacement {
     public static void main(String args[])
         {
         try
             {
             File file = new File("file.xml");
             BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
             String line = "", oldtext = "";
             while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                 {
                 oldtext += line + "\r\n";
             }
             reader.close();
             // replace a word in a file
             //String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("drink", "Love");

             //To replace a line in a file
             String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("Arial", "Times New Roman");

             FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("file.xml");
             writer.write(newtext);
             writer.close();
         }
         catch (IOException ioe)
             {
             ioe.printStackTrace();
         }
     }
}
```

But it just replace all the text to be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure that this is the format of the file you can simply do the following:

```
String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("header fontName=\"Arial\"", "header fontName=\"Times New Roman\"");
```

By the way use a `StringBuilder` to append Strings.

Comment: Actually, the format like this `<font fontName="Arial">` and it will same with the `<!-- content -->` format. I use this because i want to modify th .jrxml file from jasper.

Comment: I'd say to use a `StringBuilder` not a `StringBuffer` - unless he needs the synchronization it will be an unnecessary overhead.

Comment: @fanjavaid please clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

In your read loop `while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)` you could test if you found the `<!-- Header -->` line (and not yet the `<!-- Content -->` line), and do your replace only in the header block.

```
boolean inHeader == false;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    if (line.equals("<!-- Header -->")) {
        inHeader = true;
    } else if (line.equals("<!-- Content -->")) {
        inHeader = false;
    }
    if (inHeader) {
        line = line.replaceAll("Arial", "Times New Roman");
    }
    oldtext += line + "\r\n";
}
```

And remove the line

```
String newtext = oldtext.replaceAll("Arial", "Times New Roman");
```

EDIT: It would probably be cleaner to detect arbitrary tags rather than hardcoding Header and Content. That would require a regular expression to match `<!-- (tag) -->` and test if tag is equal to `"Header"`, but this approach is easier, of course.

Comment: I'm sorry how i can detect if it not yet `<!-- content -->` ?
Because in the loop if i found `<!-- header -->` i replace String, and looping still run until last line of file.